# Resume video after InterstitialAd loaded with Youtube Player

Tags: android, ads, youtube-data-api

I have integrated `Youtube Data API` and Google Ads in my current project. All working fine expect the video is not resuming after the `InterstitialAd` loaded properly in full screen.

If I use

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

then there is no option to play video again if Ads loaded.

If I use

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
```

then after ads loaded i have triggered pause button manually for play video in you tube player.
My purpose is to resume video after `InterstitialAd` loaded successfully without interact with `Youtubeplayer` control.

Here is my code for `onCreate()`:

```
   try {
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mAdMobInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mAdMobInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.full_screen_id));
    requestNewInterstitial();
    mAdMobInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitialAd();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }
    });

}

private void showInterstitialAd() {
    if (mAdMobInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mAdMobInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

// Initialization for Youtube Player

```
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    this.you_player = player;
    player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
    if (!wasRestored) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            if (player != null) {
                try {
                    player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    provider.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
                }
            }
            player.setFullscreen(true);
            player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(YoutubePlayerActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (you_player != null) {
        you_player.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I have also tried to initialize `YoutubePlayer` and load video in `onAdClosed()` and `onAdLoaded()` methods manually but none of them are worked.

So advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: You can try to save video time in `onAdLoaded` and then play the video from same time in `onAdClosed` hope it helps

Comment: I have already tried this thing

Comment: So  you want to pause video when interstitial ads shows and when user manually close ad then you want to resume ? am i right? @Piyush

Comment: I don't want to resume video manually. After Ad close it should be resume automatically

Comment: So calling `player.pause()` in `showInterstitialAd()` and `player.play()` in `onAdClosed()` didnt work for You? @Piyush

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have a button that shows the ad or play the YouTube player (you_player).

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
{
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
else
{
    PlayVideo(); // Do something and call you_player.loadVideo(video_Id)
}
```

In your ad Listener, instead of call PlayVideo() on onAdClosed method, just do the request for RequestNewInterstitial():

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed()
    {
        //PlayVideo();

        RequestNewInterstitial();
    }
});
```

onResume() for this activity will be call after onAdClosed() and you can call your PlayVideo() there.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (your_player == null)
    {
       youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
    else
    {
        PlayVideo();
    }
}
```